# Change char to int or string in C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am very new to C# sharp and this question may not be very well formulated, but here it goes.

I am currently generating a level consisting of more game objects. The map is generated by parsing a text file, this being my dictionary. Currently the code I have works perfectly if the index of the object does not go over 9, because of the char declaration.

I would like to know an approach on how to change this into an int maybe or into a string format (A-Z).
I attached a photo of my current "Map Generator", and highlighted the 10, which is currently read as 1 and 0.[image]

```
private void CreateLevel() {

    Tiles = new Dictionary<Point, TileScript>();

    string[] mapData = ReadLevelText();

    int mapX = mapData[0].ToCharArray().Length;
    int mapY = mapData.Length;

    Vector3 maxTile = Vector3.zero;

    // Calculates the world start point, this is the top left corner of the screen, rememeber to use on the sprite the top left pivot point
    Vector3 worldStart = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(0, Screen.height));

    for (int y = 0; y < mapY; y++) // the Y position
    {

        char[] newTiles = mapData[y].ToCharArray();

        for (int x = 0; x < mapX; x++) // the X position
        {
            // Places the tile into the level
            PlaceTile(newTiles[x].ToString(), x, y, worldStart);
        }
    }

    maxTile = Tiles[new Point(mapX-1, mapY-1)].transform.position;

    cameraMovement.SetLimit(new Vector3(maxTile.x + TileSize, maxTile.y - TileSize));
}

private void PlaceTile(string tileType, int x, int y, Vector3 worldStart) {

    int tileIndex = int.Parse(tileType);

    // Creates a new tile and makes a reference to that tile in the newTile variable
    TileScript newTile = Instantiate(tilePrefabs[tileIndex]).GetComponent<TileScript>();

    // Uses the new tile variable to change the position of the tile

    newTile.Setup(new Point(x, y), new Vector3(worldStart.x + (TileSize * x), worldStart.y - (TileSize * y), 0));

    Tiles.Add(new Point(x,y), newTile);

}
```

Comment: You should use a delimiter of sorts, like CSV does, or else you're limited to using a single char.

Comment: How would I, as a human, know that this is a 10 and not a 1 and 0? Perhaps a single byte before each int to describe it's length might be in order? Other than that I can't imagine how you could tell any language that this particular spot is a `10`.

Comment: `char` implicitly converts to `int` and vice versa. But I don't recommend going this route. Create a key-value pair between symbols-in-the-level and object-in-the-code. **and** CSV it.

Comment: I know what you are saying, but I am doing this for like 2 weeks, so yeah

Comment: You could format your numbers as hex instead of decimal, that way you can support 0-15 per character

Comment: @JNevill I believe that's the problem that the OP is trying to assess

Comment: I will probably need over 50, so 15 is too low later on.

Comment: Adding onto what @maccettura said, you could use [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) instead of decimal (Base10).

Comment: Or [base65536](https://github.com/qntm/base65536), because why not.

Comment: @Draco18s Base64 is actually practical on a standard keyboard...

Comment: @user1538301 Yes, I am aware. It was mostly a joke.

Comment: Start here: `char toWrite = (char)(index+33);//33 is smallest printing non-whitespace character`

Comment: can you give me some hits, on where should I try it in my actual code? I am new to this and everything sounds complicated :D

Comment: Also, there's no need to call `ToCharArray` on a `string`. It already is one (you can access characters by index, it has a `.Length` property, etc)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The data format you are using is not possible to parse.

Think about it, there is no way of telling which of those digits are supposed to be interpreted as a pair "10" or a single "1" or even three "101".

In these scenarios, I would recommend redoing your file format to use characters instead of digit, giving you many more symbols to work with, and/or I strongly recommend using a **delimiter** like a `,` character between each of your. The file format CSV (Comma Separated Values) does exactly this.

You could create your levels in a spreadsheet program like Excel, Numbers (mac), LibreOffice, or an online spreadsheet tool like Google Sheets. You would do this by filling in the values in the cells, and then when you are done you would export / "save as" a `.csv` file.

You can parse the `.csv` file using a .NET library like [CsvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/) (which I highly recommend using for reading CSV data in the real world)

Or, if you want to do it the quick and dirty way, you would read the file into memory using something like `File.ReadAllLines`, `Trim()` each line from the file, and then use `Split(',')` to split each line into its values. You can then iterate through your 2D array, and map it to another value if you prefer to do that!

Comment: CSV is just a bit less painful than what OP has... I assume you've actually proposed to use JSON and just typed CSV by mistake...

Comment: So, JSON would be the way to go? If so, is the approach similar?

Comment: For what you are trying to do, a simple grid of tiles, CSV is fine. 
JSON would be more complicated, but it would allow to include more nuanced data in your level maps.
Since you seem to be a beginner, either switch to using letters in the file, or use CSV.
When you get better, you might consider using JSON, but then you would probably need a level editor to work with the data efficiently. Building a level editor is a very valuable exercise you can do later on! For now, just have fun!

Comment: If you use a delimeter, then using multi-digit numbers will work

Answer (score 0):

I'd create an array of string to hold symbols, first of all -- probably "A"-"Z".  Then, change the char[] to unsigned int[] (and other changes to support that, like the ToCharArray() calls).

Then, when you place the tiles, instead of passing newTiles[x].ToString(), pass symbols[newTiles[x]].

(Truthfully, I'd probably make the symbol array char, and change the signature of PlaceTile(), if that's an option).

Comment: I will give it a try